# Both VC and Magit cannot see global .gitignore

Tags: magit, git, vc

I'm using emacs on Windows and this is long bothered me. All other apps correctly ignore all listed in global .gitignore, but in emacs they are untracked/unregistered and pollute the status window.

Comment: I just tested both vc-dir and magit. I had an unregistered file which was shown as such in both interfaces, then I added it to ~/.config/git/ignore, and both vc-dir and magit saw it as "ignored". IOW : I can't reproduce on emacs (from git master branch) and the latest magit release (I'm on GNU/Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out Emacs's `HOME` and Git's were different. I've added the `HOME` environment variable and moved my `.emacs` there. All works fine now. Thanks @YoungFrog, you made me think about my `HOME`.